# Office js : can i use web component in my Word addin using Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, office-js, web-component, word-addins

I wanted to use the web components in my Word addin but I have an error that appears with a simple test, the error is the following:
Unable to get property 'define' of undefined or null reference.

Thanks in advance !

Test.js

```
class MyProduct extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.innerHTML = "hello";
    }
}

window.customElements.define('my-product', MyProduct);        //The error is just here
```

Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Word Add-In with Commands Sample</title>

    <script type="module" src="Test.js"></script>

    
</head>
    <body>
        <my-product></my-product>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `window.customElements.define('my-product', MyProduct);`
> // Unable to get property 'define' of undefined or null reference.

The [JavaScript API for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office) is **not** the same as the FireFox/Chromium/Safari **Browser** APIs

The undefined error says: There is no `customElements` API on the `window` element.
(there is no **Browser** `window` either)

To see what you can do with JavaScript in Word see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word?view=word-js-preview

For now; no Custom Elements in Office AddIns.

Comment: I have used polyfills and the problem seems to be fixed but since using web components, I feel that my plugin is slower. It even happens that it crashes. Could it be that it creates conflicts with the Word API?

Comment: Sorry, can't help further, I left the Microsoft World 2 years ago.. 15 years was enough.. I am not a Web Component Polyfill user either.. I left because I didn't want to work with IE any more and only want to use modern tech.